# How can I resolve a MySQL syntax error from missing array item in my query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL syntax error in my query. It's built using several variables.

```
$gender = 'x';
$hepsi = implode(',', [198,201,NULL,199]);
$be = implode(',', [NULL,202,NULL]);
$ulke = 'Turkey';

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uyeler 
    where basresvar='evet' 
      AND cinsiyet='".$gender."' 
      AND kesfetgoster='evet' 
      AND id NOT IN (".$hepsi.") 
    ORDER BY FIELD (kesfetbegendikleri, '".$be."') > 0, ulke = '".$ulke."', id 
    DESC limit 10")
```

The final query is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM uyeler 
  where basresvar='evet' 
    AND cinsiyet='x' 
    AND kesfetgoster='evet' 
    AND id NOT IN (198,201,,199) 
  ORDER BY FIELD (kesfetbegendikleri, ',202,') > 0, ulke = 'Turkey', id 
  DESC limit 10
```

The empty value in the array, producing two consecutive commas in the query, generates an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '199) ORDER BY FIELD (kesfetbegendikleri, ',202,') > 0, ulke = 'Turkey', id DESC ' at line 1

How do I prevent this error?

Comment: What's the value of `$hepsi`?

Comment: You can't have that additional comma. Just replace empty values with 0.

Comment: How about using str_replace(",,",",",$value)

Comment: From where you were getting that comma separated values from an array

Comment: @user198989 That won't help if the last item in the array is empty. It'll have a trailing comma.

Comment: For anyone studying this question: the sample code is vulnerable to SQL injection (in addition to using the removed [mysql extension](https://www.php.net/intro.mysql)). See "[How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/332365/90527)", "[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174/90527)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the comma in `$hepsi`'s value (198,201, ,199) is the problem. So, if you're creating that string using `implode` from an existing array, then you could just use `array_filter` to remove empty array elements, something like this :

```
$hepsi = implode(',' array_filter($your_array));
```

If the $hepsi is already existing string then just `explode` it, apply `array_filter` and `implode` it again. Like this :

```
$hepsi = implode(',', array_filter(explode(',', $hepsi)));
```